# Gradle sonarRunner plugin adds dependency for test, causing compilation and testing to run twice

Tags: gradle, sonar-runner

I have a gradle project in scala to which I am trying to add sonarRunner. Things are working fine, but compilation and test is running twice on executing task sonarRunner as SonarRunner adds test as a dependency. However, scoverage always recompiles the code for instrumentation and then runs the tests.

Is there a way to avoid running the tests twice. I tried ignoring tests in sonarRunner task, but then test task won't run at all. I tried guarding ignore test in sonarRunner task by something like below mentioned code and that basically does not do anything.

```
task sonarRunner {
    test {
      gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { graph ->
        if (graph.hasTask('sonarRunner')) {
          enabled = false
        }
      }
    }
    dependsOn 'reportScoverage'
  }
```

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the dependency to the `test` task by overriding the `sonarRunner` task's dependencies.

```
tasks.sonarRunner {
    dependsOn = []
}
```